# Referencing a particular value of a select list

Tags: apex, visualforce, record-type, selectlist

I have a visualforce list page that lists opportunity products and some of their fields. One of these fields is a lookup to a custom object. On each row in the visualforce page, the user is given the option to lookup an existing record of the custom object or to create a new one. If the user chooses to create a new one, they are given a select list of the different record types, they select one and click Create.

Here is the section of code in my visualforce page where the select list is:

```
<apex:column headerValue="Record Type">
    <apex:selectList value="{!RecordType}" multiselect="false" size="1">
        <apex:selectOptions value="{!rectypes}"/>
    </apex:selectList><br/>                     
</apex:column>
```

Here is the section of code in the controller that deals with the record types:

```
public List<SelectOption> getrectypes() {
   List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
   options.add(new SelectOption('','--Select Record Type --'));
   for(RecordType rt:[select id,name from RecordType where sobjecttype='cust_object__c']){
     options.add(new SelectOption(rt.id,rt.name));    
   }
     return options;
   }

public String getRecordType() {
    return recType;
}


public void setRecordType(String recType) {
    this.recType= recType;
}
```

Here's the problem: I'm having trouble referencing the value of the record type that is selected from the select list. Further down in my page I have the Create link. Once the user clicks create, I need the id of the record type in the controller so that I can redirect the user to the appropriate page layout. Any idea how to get this? Any help is appreciated!

VF page:

```
<apex:commandLink action="{!onCreate}" value="Create">
</apex:commandLink>
```

Controller:

```
public PageReference onCreate(){
    return new PageReference('/a0W/e&RecordType=' + RecTypeID);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't the recType variable in your code hold that ID?

Comment: I thought that might work too, but when I tried replacing RecTypeID with recType I get this error:
Unable to Access Page
The value of the "id" parameter contains a character that is not allowed or the value exceeds the maximum allowed length. Remove the character from the parameter value or reduce the value length and resubmit. If the error still persists, report it to our Customer Support team. Provide the URL of the page you were requesting as well as any other related information.

Comment: And from what I can see in the URL, it is saying RecordType=null

Comment: You might try putting a debug statement in your set method to make sure it is getting called. Based on your snippet of code, if that is being called correctly, the recType variable should have the correct value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a day of pulling my hair out and trying everything, I found an answer.  I had to remove multiselect="false" from my selectlist. I'm not sure why this made a difference, but this attribute was not needed since it appears that multiselect defaults to false anyways. Now I am getting the id back instead of null- thanks!

Comment: Ah, interesting.  If set to true, it needs a list of Strings for the value attribute.  It must think that the string "false" is actually true.  I wonder what would happen if you used multiselect="{!IF(1==1,false,false)}" for instance.  Glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 5):

A few things look odd.  Instead of using a seprate getter and setter for getRecordType, modify your controller to replace the following:

```
public String getRecordType() {
    return recType;
}


public void setRecordType(String recType) {
    this.recType= recType;
}
```

With

```
public Id recType {get; set;}
```

Note, I did change the type here to "Id" instead of String.  Next, I think {!RecordType} may be a special variable, especially if you are using a standard controller in your visualforce page.  So, change the following:

```
<apex:selectList value="{!RecordType}" multiselect="false" size="1">
```

to:

```
<apex:selectList value="{!recType}" multiselect="false" size="1">
```

Lastly, change your onCreate method to look at recType instead of RecTypeID

```
public PageReference onCreate(){
    return new PageReference('/a0W/e&RecordType=' + recType);
}
```

If none of this works, throw some System.debugs in the getter / setters and onCreate method and check your Debug Logs for any errors or indications as to why your code isn't working.

HTH, - DL

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I'm a little confused as to where recTypeId comes in to play, should this be recType?

Comment: D'oh, sorry I changed it to recType.  Good catch.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I'm still getting null for recType. I'm going to give those System.debugs a try.